# drawRect not being called on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added a UIView to my View Controller. I set its subclass to this newDrawingView.h file.

```
//
//  newDrawingView.m
//  slate
//
//  Created by Monica Kachlon on 12/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ma. All rights reserved.
//

#import "newDrawingView.h"

@implementation newDrawingView
UIBezierPath *newPath;
CAShapeLayer * layerStyle;

- (void)startTouch:(CGPoint)point;
{
    [newPath moveToPoint:point];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"DRAWING");
}

- (void)drawShape:(CGPoint)point
{
    [newPath addLineToPoint: point]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)endTouch:(CGPoint)point {
    [newPath removeAllPoints];
}

@end
```

I manage to handle startTouch, drawShape and endTouch. But, when I do call self setNeedsDisplay - my drawRect doesn't get called..

Comment: Where did you call `drawShape` method?

Comment: I called it from a function I have that detects touch on a piece of hardware called a Slate. The drawShape function is verified as called.

Comment: I tried call drawShape method and drawRect is called

Comment: Do you realize that your `newPath` and `layerStyle` variables are global variables and not instance variables of your `newDrawingView` class?

Comment: @trunduc: What I meant was, setNeedsDisplay doesn't cause drawRect... And about global variables -  no, why does that matter?

Comment: Maybe your NSLog is hindered for some reason. there were cases in XCode where the NSLog works only in simulator but will not show when running in device.